# How to send data to the connected client who connected through socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

Hello I am new to socket programming. I am receiving data from the various devices in 5sec interval. Let's say  10 devices are connected to my socket server which keeps giving me data in 5sec interval. Each device has a unique id. These devices don't expect any message from the server. I am successfully receiving data, parsing it and entering into the database.

Now there is a mobile app which connects to this same node server which has been connected to devices as well. That mobile app/client sends a string and asks the node server that "gives me a data of for example device#3". So what I want to do is that connect device#3 to mobile app who sends the string, parse the data and keep sending data to the mobile app. Then the mobile app will receive data after the 5sec interval. This is what I want to do.

Here is the code which just receives data from 10 devices. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Fork workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('death', function(worker) {
        console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' died');
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
    net.createServer(function(socket) {
        console.log('received connection...');

        socket.on("error", function(err) {
            console.log("socket error: ")
            console.log(err.stack);
            socket.destroy();
        });
        socket.on('data', function(data) {

            //The data comes here from 10 devices. Here I run the parsing method


        });


    }).listen(PORT, HOST);
}
```

Note: I don't want to send data only once to the mobile app. I want to keep sending the data which keeps coming from the device to the mobile app until socket gets disconnected from the mobile app.

Comment: You need to keep a map of socket ID and device ID in order to know which socket connection to point to the app. Otherwise, you don't know which device has what ID on your server.

Comment: @AbhyuditJain can you write some code of how can I do it ?